# Dynamic floating bubbles..using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a plugin in Jquery, where I can implement a floating bubble. For example if i give the number 5 as input, it has to show 5 bubbles. The size of the bubble also grows based on my input.. how I can achieve this?

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://www.soyos.net/tl_files/demos/bubbles/

Comment: @Waynn Lue: This has nothing to do with [css-selectors] or [css-floating], or any of [css] at all. There is no need to fill up the tag field with irrelevant tags.

Comment: @BoltClock Ah, I wasn't sure if those were relevant or not so I didn't touch them. Thanks for letting me know. :)

Answer (score 0):

For this you can try HTML canvas element and draw the bubbles on it. Also you can change the size and position of bubbles.
[Canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_canvas.asp)

Comment: Thanks Digvijay.. it helps me to reach first level of my requirement. Thanks a lot